# Azure Eventhub - how to resend/replay the same batch of events to the same Eventhub client

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Lets say, when transient fault occurs while processing batch of events from Azure EventHub & transient fault continues even after retries then what kind of exception can be thrown to Eventhub from processor? so that Azure eventhub can able to send same batch of events again (replay) to the same processor instance (without moving forward the checkpointer) for reprocessing.

Package "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="5.1.2"

Azure function is the client which runs on AKS with KEDA scaling configuration

Comment: Please provide the package and version that you're using.   Please also detail which client type is being used to read events; a code sample that demonstrates use would be very helpful.

Comment: details updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell - there is no exception that your code can throw that would stop checkpointing in an Azure Function app.

Functions has a unique model in that checkpointing is automatic and it moves forward regardless of success or failure of the processing code that is executing.

The most common pattern for when your Function encounters an error where it cannot process an event is to dead-letter it so that another application can revisit and process it in the future.  More detail and other patterns to consider can be found in the article [Resilient Event Hubs and Functions design](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/serverless/event-hubs-functions/resilient-design#strategies-for-failures-and-corrupt-data).

If none of these work in your application scenario, your best path forward would likely be to consider not using Functions as a host platform and use the event processor directly in your application.  That would give you full control over when checkpoints are emitted.

Comment: Azure function code has to throw uncaught exception then that would stop checkpointing

Comment: No; all exceptions are handled and result in a checkpoint being written.

Comment: @ jesse squire, No. I have tested it, if Azure function app throws unhanding exception then check pointing not happening as a result event hub replay the same dataset on next trigger provided Azure function decorated with "ExponentialBackoffRetry" attribute. Refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#:~:text=A%20retry%20policy,batch%20has%20finished

Comment: If you're decorating with the retry attribute, your code will have additional attempts at running before a checkpoint is emitted.  However, after all retries have taken place, a checkpoint will be written regardless of success or failure.

Comment: In case you're interested in the details, invocation of your code and retries are performed by an executor that captures and logs exceptions.  Once that process is complete, control returns to the trigger's listener which then writes the checkpoint.   The source can be found here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/src/Listeners/EventHubListener.cs#L167

Comment: In my case, in order to avoid data loss I have to go with infinite retry (-1) by using [ExponentialBackoffRetry(-1, "00:00:04", "00:15:00")] so a checkpoint will not be written until retry succeeds.